# Alert value in loop [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a page in which I want to put a Name, Image URL, Description in alert and display this info in a loop. But it's not working for me!

Here is the code

```
    let nameArr = [companyName];
    let logoArr = [companyLogo];
    let logoImgList = [];
    let companyList = "";
    let aboutCompanyArr = [aboutCompany];

    for(let i=0; i < logoArr.length; i++){
        logoImgList[i] = "<img src='" + logoArr[i] + "' width=150 height=150>"; //you don't need to add directory here, Image URLs should be direct!
    }
    for(let i=0; i < nameArr.length; i++){
        companyList += "<div class='companyList'>" + logoImgList[i] + "<br>" + nameArr[i] + "<br>" + aboutCompanyArr[i] + "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("companyList").innerHTML = companyList;
```

Comment: <img> component doesn't need the close tag? like <img src="" />, also <br />

Comment: image, text and description shown but not in loop, it replaces the all info

Comment: add some screenshots of the result. i can't get you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tb0xpg2e/ check this

Comment: when i click Add a company second time, it replaces the info, in don't want to replace it, i want to show loop

Comment: do you want to add 2 companies instead of removing the old one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211040/discussion-between-o-o-and-ahsen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nameArr=[];
var logoArr=[];
var aboutCompanyArr=[];
function addCompany(){

    let companyName = prompt("Enter the company name:");
    let companyLogo = prompt("Copy and paste URL company logo:");
    let aboutCompany = prompt("Say a little about the company:");

    nameArr.push(companyName);
    logoArr.push(companyLogo);
    aboutCompanyArr.push(aboutCompany);
    let logoImgList = [];
    let companyList = "";
    //let companyImgList = [];


        for(let i=0; i < logoArr.length; i++){

            logoImgList[i] = "<img src='" + logoArr[i] + "' width=150 height=150/>"; //you don't need to add directory here, Image URLs should be direct!

        }
        for(let i=0; i < nameArr.length; i++){
            companyList += "<div class='companyList'>" + logoImgList[i] + "<br>" + nameArr[i] + "<br/>" + aboutCompanyArr[i] + "</div>";
        }
        document.getElementById("companyList").innerHTML = companyList;
}
```

Check this.
I've updated the code.